# amCharts export onclick and action

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to work onclick and action of a menu item at same time in amCharts export menu? I have an amChart with custom menu items. When a menu item is clicked I want to show a div and set its action as draw, but click function is not working when action is set. Is there any way to work both click and action in a same menu item?

Code for menu is:

```
"menu": [{
  "label": "Annotated Data",
  "action": "draw",
  "click": function () {
    $('.center').show();
    $('#start_button').show();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct to assume that `action` property overrides `click`.

To work around that, we can use [`menuReviver`](https://github.com/amcharts/export#menu-item-reviver) to attach additional custom click events directly to menu elements, without interfering with the business of Export plugin's menu:

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true,
  "menuReviver": function(cfg, li) {
    if (cfg.action == "draw") {
      $(li).click(function() {
        $('.center').show();
        $('#start_button').show();
      });
    }
    return li;
  },
  "menu": [{
    "label": "Annotated Data",
    "action": "draw"
  }]
}
```